# Probleme with Google Direction Matrix API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

I tried to find the **duration_in_traffic** value from API.

When I use the the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) object like this :

```
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins         : i === 0 ? [origin] : [destination],
    destinations    : i === 0 ? [destination] : [origin],
    travelMode      : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    drivingOptions  : {
        departureTime   : departureTime[i],
        trafficModel    : google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC
    }
}, callbackCar);
```

The result don't contains duration_in_traffic field.

---

When I use instead the GET API service with JSONP the console contains an **Unexpected token : error ...**

```
getDelay: function() {
    return $resource('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json', {
        key: ACCESS.ggAPI,
        origins: "@origins",
        destinations: "@destinations",
        language: "fr-FR",
        mode: "@mode",
        transit_mode: "@transitMode",
        traffic_model: "@traffic_model"
    }, {                        
        get: {
            method: 'JSONP'
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to use GET instead JSONP, I have a CORS issue...

When I try to put the uri built by the angular service in a other window, i can find the correct result :

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "93200 Saint-Denis, France" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "95500 Gonesse, France" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "16,7 km",
                  "value" : 16746
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 minutes",
                  "value" : 1133
               },
               **"duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "23 minutes",
                  "value" : 1391
               },**
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you a Google Maps Premium Plan customer?

Comment: No simply stabdard Plan, but this feature is free no ? I thought Google had made this free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a Premium Plan you cannot get the `duration_in_traffic` attribute.

> The total duration of this leg, taking into account the traffic conditions indicated by the trafficModel property. This property may be undefined as the duration may be unknown. **Only available to Premium Plan customers** when drivingOptions is defined when making the request.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsLeg)